# How do I use php's "RecursiveArrayIterator" in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel 5.6, and in my controller I have

```
use RecursiveIteratorIterator;
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\RecursiveArrayIterator' not found
```

So I'm being a little simplistic about it. Obviously RecursiveIteratorIterator is not a laravel function, but rather a core php function. But after reading this post https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/ I'm still no clearer on where to find it, or how to reference it properly.

I suppose I was expecting that all "native" php functions would just be available?

Help?

Comment: Its core code so try `use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;`

Comment: Can you show us the line that's generating the `Class not found` error?

Comment: It was     `$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($request, TRUE)),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to put a backslash in front (No need to put `use ...` at the top), to specify a root/global class:

```
\RecursiveIteratorIterator;
```

For more information, refer to the PHP documentation [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php):

> Example #3 Accessing internal classes in namespaces

```
<?php
namespace foo;
$a = new \stdClass;

function test(\ArrayObject $typehintexample = null) {}

$a = \DirectoryIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO;

// extending an internal or global class
class MyException extends \Exception {}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks. So it seems the `use \RecursiveIteratorIterator; ` is uneccessary (at the top), but in the body, prefix the function with a "\" does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be mention, it looks like you are only importing

`use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;`

and also calling `RecursiveArrayIterator` somewhere in the code. try importing both.

```
   use \RecursiveIteratorIterator;
   use \RecursiveArrayIterator;
```